# Counting rows based on multiple conditions and add to list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file which is needed for some summarizing statistics and I have a list of various robots and the status of their execution. My issue is that I've indexed them to a new dataframe using the following code:

```
x1 = df["Title"].value_counts().index.tolist()
```

I have several columns where eg. 'Title' (Name of specific robot) is in column A and a column D named 'Status'(where it either states Completed or Failed)

How do I count the number of occurrences of the specific robot in column A with the condition that is says completed in column D?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['Robot1', 'Robot1', 'Robot3', 'Robot1', 'Robot3'], 'Status':['Completed', 'Failed', 'Running', 'Completed', 'Completed']})

print(df.to_string(index=False))

Title       Status
Robot1      Completed
Robot1      Failed
Robot3      Running
Robot1      Completed
Robot3      Completed
```

Comment: difficult to answer without having an example of the data and the expected output

Comment: Sorry I am very new to coding and this platform and cannot post pictures

Comment: Good, because pictures are useless, [reproducible data **as text**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) is uselful ;)

Comment: Thank you - I will look into making a better question :)

Comment: I'm following the question, looking forward to your update ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just slice before `value_counts`:

```
df.loc[df['Status'].eq('Completed'), 'Title'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Robot1    2
Robot3    1
Name: Title, dtype: int64
```